# How do I group a date field by week, where the weeks start on Saturday?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I'm going to go 'duh' when I see the answer to this, but nonetheless:

How do I group a date field by week, where the weeks start on Saturday?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to first use [**DATEFIRST**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) to set `Saturday` as the first day of your week. Value **1** denotes Monday and value **6** denotes the day Saturday. Then you can use the [**DATEPART**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) with `week` or `wk` or `ww` to group your date column values.

You can see in the below sample data that values for dates `2012-01-07` and `2012-01-08` are grouped under weekno **2** because *2012-01-07* is a *Saturday*. *January 1* of any year is always first week of the year.

[**Click here to view the output in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a0b4/3)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE weekdays
(
    datevalue    datetime NOT NULL
  , numericvalue INT      NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO weekdays (datevalue, numericvalue) VALUES
  ('2012-01-01', 4),
  ('2012-01-02', 1),
  ('2012-01-07', 2),
  ('2012-01-08', 8),
  ('2012-01-14', 3),
  ('2012-01-15', 2),
  ('2012-01-19', 6);

SET DATEFIRST 6;

SELECT      DATEPART(wk, datevalue)     weekno
        ,   SUM(numericvalue)           totalvalue
FROM        weekdays
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, datevalue)
```

*Output*:

```
weekno totalvalue
------ ----------
  1        5
  2       10
  3       11
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `DATEPART` function as:

```
SELECT      DATEPART(wk, Date), SUM(Value)
FROM        Table
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, Date)
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, untested as I don't have SQL Server handy, though a straight translation into MySQL seemed to work as expected:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT your_date_field, 
               DATEADD(D, 
               -(DATEPART(DW,your_date_field) MOD 7), your_date_field) AS saturday 
          FROM your_table) 
 GROUP BY saturday
 ORDER BY your_date_field
```

Comment: +1 for effort.  Can't tell you if it worked or not though since Siva's answer wasn't so awesome.

Comment: That's really about the only thing I truly envy from other dbms's... the ability to use aliases from the select clause in other parts of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Had real problems with this but this prevents extra tables and DATEFIRST which may be prevented from been SET. Here is my answer using the known date method and call records being retrieved.

19000101  = Monday - always easy to remember therefore set Saturday as 19000106

```
SELECT MIN(dateadd(day, datediff(
day,'19000106', CallRecords.CallStartTime)/7*7, '19000106')) 
AS CallStartTime
FROM CallRecords 
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,'19000106', CallRecords.CallStartTime)/7
```

Tested on SQL Server and SQL Server Compact 4.0

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, the method name is `DATE_PART()`