# group by weekly date

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I want to group data weekly where weekly dates are stored in different table.I can do it by doing datepart and then i can group them by week but the problem is weekly dates which i have are keep changing sometime the week starts from saturday sometime sunday.
for example :

```
2022-03-27 00:00:00.000
2022-04-03 00:00:00.000
2022-04-10 00:00:00.000
2022-04-17 00:00:00.000
2022-04-24 00:00:00.000
2022-04-30 00:00:00.000
2022-05-08 00:00:00.000
2022-05-15 00:00:00.000
2022-05-22 00:00:00.000
```

The above dates are week dates on which report should be generated ..
for example : from 2022-03-27 00:00:00.000 to 2022-04-03 00:00:00.000 it will be one row in report .from 2022-04-03 00:00:00.000 to 2022-04-10 00:00:00.000 .it will be second row and so on.

I am able to do it by using datepart on date and then calculating week of year but due to dates in my case are not uniform its missing  data for some dates ..

How can i achieve that ? any advice ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424395/how-do-i-group-a-date-field-by-week-where-the-weeks-start-on-saturday

Comment: please share desired outputs , table create statements, sql fiddle if possible

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the week of an arbitrary date is the latest date in the weeks table that is on or before that date.

So you could do something like this

```
SELECT d.TheDate, w.StartOfWeek
FROM TheData d
    INNER JOIN (
        -- Make a lookup table.
        SELECT d.TheDate, MAX(w.StartOfWeek) AS StartOfWeek
        FROM TheData d
            INNER JOIN Weeks w 
              ON d.TheDate >= w.StartOfWeek
        GROUP BY d.TheDate
    ) w
        ON d.TheDate = w.TheDate
```

That's assumin that `Weeks` contains all weeks and doesn't have any gaps...

Comment: but that will not show data in between in these two dates ..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.
For example: suppose I have `TheDate = '2022-04-19'`, then the subquery will get `StartOfWeek = '2022-04-17'` -- the greatest element of the `Weeks` table that is less than `TheDate`.

Comment: In the above, `GROUP BY w.StartOfWeek` and compute some aggregates from `TheData` to end up with one row per week.